# Where is a good place to learn the latest iphone development?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just started objective-c, after having learnt C. I was looking online for some good tutorials, but all of them had functions that are deprecated in the latest version or new functions. I was wondering if you knew of any places that had a good iphone 6.1 tutorial, or if there was any way on XCode to develop for older versions.
Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. There are a ton of books on this subject, Novice to Advanced.

Comment: @WrightsCS how many are for the latest version though?

Comment: iOS 6 is pretty old now. There are still some books on iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello scrblnrd3 welcome to the world of Objective-C and iOS programming. Whether you are a novice or a seasoned developer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) is the place to go to if you looking for tutorials on latest iOS topics.

There are also apple developer documents which you can use to learn and they are pretty exhaustive. I'd suggest you start by reading [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started) articles.

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329029/best-ios-development-tutorials) question also lists some good websites for iOS tutorials.

Comment: Try this document for an introduction to Objective-C :) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html